# Does unbind('click') remove onclick?

Tags: jquery

I'm running the following:

```
$("#myelement").unbind('click');
```

When I view `$("#myelement")[0].onclick` in the VS.NET 2010 Watch window, I see `"{...}".`

Should `unbind('click')` remove `onclick` events?

Comment: @MohammadAdil Right, but can event handlers attached with onclick="..." be unbound with `.unbind()`? that's the question (the way i understand it atleast)

Comment: It removes them in the sense that clicking the element(s) won't trigger whatever functions have been bound before. How jQuery is doing it "behind the scenes" isn't really important, but it's probably not setting the `onclick` to null.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/AwPnn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not remove the `onclick` event, as is demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj8uD/).

Binded events are stored within jQuery objects, therefore, `unbind` just removes the event from the jQuery object.

`unbind` will only remove events that have been attached using the jQuery `bind` method and/or the deprecated `live` method.

If you want to reset the actual `onclick` event using jQuery, then just use one of the following methods:

```
$('#myelement').attr('onclick','');
$('#myelement').removeAttr('onclick');
```

If you want to add an event to specifically the `onclick` of an element *(not bind a jQuery click event)*, then simply use the following:

```
$('#myelement').attr('onclick','alert(\'hello\')');
```

***I would strongly disadvise the above method though as I am sure you can appreciate, adding a function to this would be a little tricky escaping all of the quotes...***

---

In addition, might I advise you use the `on` and `off` jQuery methods instead. Whilst these are only available in newer versions of jQuery, they are the preferred method as stated here:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

See the following for more information:

1. [jQuery Attr Method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
2. [jQuery Bind Method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
3. [jQuery Unbind Method](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
4. [jQuery On Method](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
5. [jQuery Off Method](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: After doing the above resets, does $('#myelement').click(function(){...}); work to wire up a new event against onclick?

Comment: @4thSpace Ooo wait, sorry i misread what you said. Not it does not, I will update my answer

Comment: @4thSpace Answer updated. If you want to specifically change the `onclick` attribute of an element then use what I have suggested, but as explained in my answer, I strongly discourage it :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$('#myelement').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

Comment: or we can do it using $('#myelement').removeAttr('onclick');